# python (flask) deployment issue on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, deployment, gunicorn

I have a small flask todo app, and trying to deploy it in heroku, but getting errors and I am unable to solve it, source code is here, this is working perfectly,

error screenshot can be seen here => http://prntscr.com/kyfwmy

Here is my `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, url_for, redirect
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo, pymongo
import sys, time
from bson.json_util import dumps, ObjectId

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME']='todo'
app.config['MONGO_URI']='mongodb://todo_task:todo_task*123*@ds111082.mlab.com:11082/todo'

mongo = PyMongo(app)

cors = CORS(app, resources={r'/ajax/*': {"origins": '*'}})



@app.route('/')
def index():
    _tasks = mongo.db.tasks.find().sort('created_at', pymongo.DESCENDING)
    return  render_template('index.html', tasks=_tasks)

@app.route('/add_task', methods=['POST'])
def add_task():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tasks = mongo.db.tasks
        data = {
            'task': request.form['task'],
            'status': 'view', 
            'created_at': time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'), 
            'updated_at': time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
            }
        tasks.insert(data)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/destroy_task')
def task_destroy():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        id = request.args.get('id')
        tasks = mongo.db.tasks
        result = tasks.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(id)})
        tasks.remove(result)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/ajax/task_update', methods=['POST'])
def task_update():
    id = request.form['id']
    tasks = mongo.db.tasks
    result = tasks.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(id)})

    if result['status'] == 'completed':
        result['status'] = 'view'
        res = {"status": 'view'}
    else:
        result['status'] = 'completed'
        res = {"status": 'completed'}

    result['updated_at'] = time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

    tasks.save(result)

    return jsonify({'status': res})

@app.route('/actives')
def actives():
    tasks = mongo.db.tasks
    _tasks = tasks.find({'status': 'view'}).sort('created_at', pymongo.DESCENDING)
    return  render_template('index.html', tasks=_tasks)

@app.route('/completes')
def completes():
    tasks = mongo.db.tasks
    _tasks = tasks.find({'status': 'completed'}).sort('created_at', pymongo.DESCENDING)
    return  render_template('index.html', tasks=_tasks)

@app.route('/clear_completes')
def clear_completes():
    tasks = mongo.db.tasks
    tasks.remove({'status': 'completed'})
    return redirect(url_for('index'))



app.run(debug=True)
```

https://github.com/IrfanMumtaz/python-todo-app

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post text in screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Also, please include relevant code _here_ as a [mcve]. We shouldn't have to go off-site to understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not telling Flask what port to use, so it's trying to use port 5000 (its default):

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Heroku [tells you what port to use via the `PORT` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers). You need to use that variable's value when you run your application.

Something like this should work:

```
import os

# ...

app.run(port=os.getenv('PORT', 5000))
```

You will probably also want to [disable debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#debug-mode):

> ### Attention:
>
> Even though the interactive debugger does not work in forking environments (which makes it nearly impossible to use on production servers), it still allows the execution of arbitrary code. This makes it a major security risk and therefore it **must never be used on production machines**.